# How to read sql ce(.sdf file) database/table from SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-ce

I want to read **`.SDF file(3.5)`** from **SQL Server Integration Service 2008**.

How can I do this?

Please provide me any link/tutorials for this.

Comment: Are you able to make Connection?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried Native OLE DB with different options; "Microsoft jet 4.0 OLE DB provider" and "Microsoft OLE DB sample provider". Both case failed saying Error in initializing provider, Unrecognized DB format. I'm new to this SSIS things...Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are out of luck regarding SSIS, you can only use the OLEDB connection as a SQL Server Compact Data Source, and it has severe limitations.

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, and therefore it is difficult for me to propose a solution.

I did some experiments with SQLCLR once, but they also rely on the OLEDB provider:

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2008/10/accessing-sql-compact-from-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio in Server Explorer -> add connection and change Provider to "Microsoft Sql Server Compact 4" and then you browse to .sdf file. Now, you can do every thing like Sql server in VS